# Django & Postgres: ProgammerError column of relation does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I have my models defined as:

```
class NModels(models.Model):
    model_name=models.TextField(max_length=30, default='DEFVAL')

class ModelRun(models.Model):
    currmodel= models.ForeignKey(NModels)
    run_name = models.TextField(max_length=20)

class ModelRegion(models.Model):
    model_run = models.ForeignKey(ModelRun)
    region = models.TextField(max_length=20)

class ModelImages(models.Model):
    model_region = models.ForeignKey(ModelRegion)
    map_type = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    map_path = models.TextField(max_length=100)
```

When I go to submit my form the debug returns:

```
Exception Value: column "model_name" of relation "wxpoint_nmodels" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "wxpoint_nmodels" ("model_name") VALUES ('GFS')
```

In my views.py:

```
def model_page(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        new_model_image = request.POST['GFS']
        gfsmodel = NModels.objects.create(model_name=new_model_image)
        currentmodelrun = ModelRun.objects.create(currmodel=gfsmodel, run_name='gfs00z')
        currentmodelregion = ModelRegion.objects.create(model_run=currentmodelrun, region='USA')
        myimage = ModelImages.objects.create(model_region=currentmodelregion, map_type="temps", 
            map_path='images/GFS2mt12z.gif', timestep="00hr")
        return render(request, 'models.html', {'new_model_image': myimage.map_path, })
    return render(request, 'models.html')
```

When I run my unit tests, everything thing works fine, so i'm not sure why i'm getting this error.

I've done python3 manage.py make migrations, and migrate, syncdb and still get the same error. In the psql, \l shows the database for my app, although \d returns no relations found.

EDIT:

python3 manage.py showmigrations yields:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
wxpoint
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_modelrun
 [X] 0003_modelregion
 [X] 0004_modelimages
 [X] 0005_auto_20150611_0341
```

EDIT2:
Running `python3 manage.py dbshell` then `\d+ wxpoint_nmodels`:

```
Column |  Type   |                          Modifiers                           | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('wxpoint_nmodels_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `makemigrations appname`? Also, check what the `NModel` import is, (incase you have two models of same name in different namespace?)

Comment: @Sayse I tried `make migrations appname` and I still get the same error. In the manage.py shell, NModels returns wxpoint.models.NModels

Comment: @Sayse I ran `python3 manage.py dbshell` to look at the current database state it doesn't show a column for model_name in my NModel relation and has a side of 0 bytes. All the other tables are bigger and size and include all the columns. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try `makemigrations --fake` to try to force `migrate` to find your change or just `migrate appname`

Comment: @Sayse I changed the model_name to be a primary key and `migrate` returns an error: `ProgrammingError: column "model_name" named in key does not exist`

Comment: Well it doesn't really make sense for a name to be a primary key since it can't be incremented. If you've changed it then you need to do makemigrations before a migrate will notice your change

Comment: Also, what version of Django are we working with here?

Comment: @Sayse Version 1.8. I updated the OP to include the results when I look at the NModel relation. It doesn't seem like it is recognizing the model_name field, as it's only showing the id.

Comment: It is possible it is a bug that has been fixed sometime between 1.8 and 1.8.2 but I couldn't answer that. You could try forcing the change through by renaming the field to something else, making a migration, renaming back, and making another migration to change it back.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that migration files are pretty human readable so you may want to open your `wxpoint` ones and see if anything about the name is in them

Comment: @Sayse When I rename the field, I did `makemigrations` then on migrate it returns: `ProgrammingError: column "model_name" does not exist`. Maybe it is a bug

Comment: The only thing I could suggest is looking through your migration files and seeing if model_name is there, You could always just delete all your migration files and remake them but that is risky and could affect your existing data

Comment: @Sayse I did delete my migration files initially and have just now deleted them to retry the migration. That could be the problem. I could try dropping the table.

Comment: Ahh very possible, I was just about to suggest writing your own migration file and found that `migrations.AddField` uses a parameter called `model_name` and im wondering if it is your own field name that is the problem, have you tried just naming it `name`?

Comment: @Sayse I dropped the tables in the `manage.py dbshell` and then retried make migrations, migrate, and syncdb, but now the relations are not showing up in the shell.